# Creating an updating GUI, IE Video or Blog service in VB.net Winforms

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms

First of all I would like to thank everyone on this forum, as you have made some of my friends greatest projects successful and I was hoping one of these projects can be done without them.

Now I want to expand to other services. I want to make an app in WinForms or WPF (But im still learning XAML so if you can it would help to answer for winforms) that constantly updates data and displays pictures or video in a row/rows. Like almost Moviebox for iPhone or Showbox for android. How movies are updated constantly without updating the app. (Im not promting piracy, its just the best example I could think of). And when you click on the movie(Which is a picture) it gives a description and picture and even a youtube video.

It kinda would work like a blog reader.... I think?

I think I will need a server and I will probably need a database. But sadly , i'm still a beginner, but willing to learn. Thanks and if you need any more info, please just ask. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 The answer! I think? Any helpers?

Comment: Please remove story of you life from your post and ad for your site as it is unclear how it relates to your question... It looks like you are looking for RSS reader sample (which would be offtopic as searchin for tools), but it kind of hard to see due to lot of unrelated text/thank you notes.

Comment: I've seen you before. I don't know where, but I know I have...

Comment: Seen? Or heard about me? Im not that famous. Was it on StackOverFlow? II've asked a few questions B4. @Taconut

Comment: I've seen your website and I know I've talked to you at some point. I just don't know where. Its this really trippy Deja Vu kind of thing. I knew what your website looked like even before opening it. I even remembered that sick skull avatar on the "site manager". This is really freaking weird.

Comment: @taconut My twitter name is d0lb33 if that helps.

Comment: @Alexei I am looking into RSS feeds now but so far I see they are for websites not really programs.

Comment: @Taconut maybe even reddit?

Comment: @D0LB33 Yeah. Probably Reddit (I guess)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211380.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2 This MSDN example explained everything I needed in full!